# Date Styles in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to input a specific date type into my mysql database.

The format is `dd-'month'-yy` where month is the abbreviated month. For example, I would like to put in, `12-DEC-78` which would be December 12, 1978.

I've tried inputting that style with just the `DATE` data type, but it just reformats to 0's- like 0000-00-00.

I've looked all over the MySQL page itself and have had no luck with finding a data type that supports this format at table creation. Is there a type I'm overlooking or a setting to switch over to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert that date into a MySQL friendly format. [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) will do that for you:

```
STR_TO_DATE('12-DEC-78', "%d-%b-%y")
```

Comment: So if I'm working with a CSV file to load data, I'll need a trigger or function in order to do this?

Comment: If you're loading the data directly from the CSV file, yes, you would need something to call that function for you.

Comment: To clarify, I have the dates all ready to go in the csv file, is there an inherent way to do this with the actual table creation process?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

1. Change the `DATE` type to char(9), name "olddate" This allows you to insert '12-Dec-78' format.
2. After you have inserted the CSV, create a new column with `DATE` type, name "newdate"
3. UPDATE table SET newdate=STR_TO_DATE(oldate, "%d-%b-%y")
4. Remove olddate column